как быть с ошибкой "multiple definition" для глобальных переменных
есть вот глобальная переменная в .hpp файле:
#ifndef HEADER_HPP
#define HEADER_HPP

namespace myLib
{
    unsigned value;
}

#endif

этот файл подключается в другие хеадеры,эти хеадеры подключаются в cpp файлы
всё компилируется, но при линковке появляется ошибка "multiple definition of
(используется cmake для сборки)

inline, extern...
